# Why Node as well as Node.prototype has constant ELEMENT_NODE

Tags: javascript, dom

Reading the [specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node) I would have thought that either `Node` or `Node.prototype` have the nodeType values `ELEMENT_NODE`, `ATTRIBUTE_NODE`, etc. defined. However, it turns out (at least in Firefox) you can access them through both instances *and* classes.

```js
console.log(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
console.log(Node.prototype.ELEMENT_NODE)
```

Is this a shortcoming of the specs? Did I miss something while reading?
A clarification would be great!

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense. I'd have expected it to be only on `Node`, not on `Node.prototype`

Comment: It certainly helps to write easier code because you can just look into this.NODE_ELEMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are [*constants*](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-constant) (`const`) defined on the Interface.

From the [WebIDL specs](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#ref-for-dfn-constant%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A1):

> Constants are not associated with particular instances of the interface or callback interface on which they appear. It is language binding specific whether constants are exposed on instances.
>
> > The ECMAScript language binding does however allow constants to be accessed through objects implementing the IDL interfaces on which the constants are declared. For example, with the following IDL:
> >
> > ```
> > [Exposed=Window]
> > interface A {
> >  const short rambaldi = 47;
> > };
> > ```
> >
> > the constant value can be accessed in ECMAScript either as `A.rambaldi` or `instanceOfA.rambaldi`.

So just like any other `const` defined on an Interface, you can access it either on the Interface directly, or on any instance, hence implementers simply expose it on the prototype too.